# get the value of text field using javascript and post it in action of the form

Tags: php, javascript, url, post, textfield

hi i have a PHP page
and i want to take the value of the text field and post it in the action or in the url
i want to put the page number in the url
i am numbering the pages

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?&p=$pgNumber"; ?>" method="post" name="page" >
Go to page: <input name="productid" type="text" size="3" />
<input name="Go" type="submit" value="Go" onclick="<?php $pgNumber=$_GET['productid']; ?>" />
</form>
```

but PHP is server side so i should put a javascript function which add "?&p=6" at the end of the url
  the "p" is the page number

please guys i know nothing about javascript

thanks in advanced!

Comment: Why don't use the GET method in the form? you don't need to use Javascript to accomplish your task.

Comment: please could you tell me how?? please

Comment: What is the problem with above code? it should render `yourpage.php?&p=6` if `pgNumber = 6` in action attribute of form. and when you will post the form it will hit the above URL. why you need javascript for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have such form tag instead:

```html
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="page" onsubmit="this.action += '?p=' + this.elements['productid'].value;">
```

This will append the value of the textbox to the submitted URL and still preserve the POST method.

Comment: this is what am talking about thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks alot man :D

Comment: You should use this code carefully because it could introduce security issues. This solution requires a proper sanitization of the productid parameter before writing in the html page using javascript.

Comment: @Fab the value is sent anyway to the PHP, can't see any additional security problem. ?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: I mean, the onsubmit method updates the dom (action="something_else...") with a value entered by the user. Maybe I'm wrong, but I always sanitize a value before outputting in a html page.

Comment: @Fab form action is not really DOM... it has no effect except changing the target URL of the submitted form. In case of malicious code in the textbox, invalid URL will be created and should be handled in the receiving PHP code. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"; ?>" method="get" name="page" >
Go to page: <input name="p" type="text" size="3" />
<input name="Go" type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

When you submit the form clicking the "Go" button, the page will be refreshed with the "?p=xxx" appended.

Comment: this solve my problem but the url will be:
"http://localhost/movies/Action&Adventure_n.php?p=6&Go=Go"

Comment: You need not give a name for the submit element if you don't need its value.

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?&p=$pgNumber"; ?>" method="post" name="page" >
Go to page: <input name="productid" type="text" size="3" />
<input name="Go" type="submit" value="Go" onclick="<?php $pgNumber=$_GET['productid']; ?>" />
</form>
```

to

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?&p=$pgNumber"; ?>" method="get" name="page" >
Go to page: <input name="productid" type="text" size="3" />
<input name="Go" type="submit" value="Go" onclick="<?php $pgNumber=$_GET['productid']; ?>" />
</form>
```

The difference is in the form method attribute. When method type is get, you will get the form elements and values in the URL. Try it out and let know if it works.

Comment: The requested URL /movies/<br /><b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: pgNumber in <b>C:\wamp\www\movies\Action&Adventure_n.php</b> on line <b>803</b><br />/movies/Action&Adventure_n.php was not found on this server

Comment: the line 803 is:
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?&p=$pgNumber"; ?>" method="get" name="page" >

Comment: Well it seems like the $pgNumber variable you are using is not defined at all. Where is it supposed to come from?

Comment: You should look at Shadow Wizard's answer below. I believe that is what you are looking for.